# My NSView View resizes to it's original size whenever i resize my window

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, resize, nsview

This is what i am doing

1. Create a new 10.9 cocoa application
2. Drag a drop a custom view to the top right corner - by leaving the default size of the custom view
3. In Appdelegate.h i create this line by cmd+drag -> @property (weak) IBOutlet NSView *myView;
4. In Appdelegate.m i synthesize like -> @synthesize myView;

Then i add this code

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

    [myView setWantsLayer:YES];
    myView.layer.backgroundColor = CGColorCreateGenericRGB(0,0,0,0.5);


    NSRect vFrame = myView.frame;

    vFrame.origin.x = 0;
    vFrame.origin.y = 0;

    vFrame.size.width = 100;
    vFrame.size.height = 100;

    [myView setFrame:vFrame];


}
```

The question i have is - whenever i resize my window the myView (my NSView) switches to to it original position and size. All i want it it should not change it's origin or size even if i resize

Comment: Have you enabled autolayout on your xib?

Comment: Autoresizing  Checkbox is enabled by default in my xib - SO it's ON

Comment: Oh, gees...  Are you a teenager?  What does Google tell you about autolayout?  Help yourself.

Comment: Autoresizing is different from autolayout. Select your xib and on the right panel of xcode (Utilities), select the first tab (file inspector) check if `Use Autolayout` is checked.

Comment: Got it now!. Autolayout is different from Autoresize sub views.

Comment: So, did unchecking that fix your problem?